# deleting a large group of photos in photos (like from a game cam)

Tags: photos

I am trying to delete about 1000 photos taken on a game camera and transferred to Photos.  .  Is their a quick way to do this or do I have to do it one at a time in Photos ?

Answer (score 2):

You can shift select & delete all at one go, if you set the view correctly…

- Enable the Sidebar  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>S</kbd>
- Set the view to Albums > All Photos
- Click the first in the series
- Hold  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  & click the last
- Either right click & choose "Delete *nnn* Photos" or hit  <kbd>Delete ⌦</kbd>  [with confirmation] or
   <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Backspace ⇤</kbd>  [with no confirmation]

If the pictures are not entirely sequential, you can creat more complex selections using  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  click &  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  click.